# How to recall an ajax on failure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Here is my ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "getProduct",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: {
            productid: $("#serviceequip1").val()
            },
        error: function(){  
        },
        success: function(xml){   
            $(xml).find("product").each(function()
            {

                //do something.. 
            });


        }
    });
```

I have checked in development mode of browser, sometimes it shows 505 error for ajax call.

Please suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function to do ajax call. When error, call the function again.

```
 function getProduct(){
 $.ajax({
        url: "getProduct",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: {
            productid: $("#serviceequip1").val()
            },
        error: function(){ 
                setTimeout(getProduct, 200);
        },
        success: function(xml){   
            $(xml).find("product").each(function()
            {
                //do something.. 
            });
        }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write this ajax call inside a method and in the failure block of ajax just call the method again.

```
function ajaxCall(){
 $.ajax({
        url: "getProduct",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: {
            productid: $("#serviceequip1").val()
            },
        error: function(){  
ajaxCall();
        },
        success: function(xml){   
            $(xml).find("product").each(function()
            {

                //do something.. 
            });


        }
    });
}
```